# Gmail canned response only to senders not in my contact list

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, gmail-canned-response

How do I filter a canned response to send to people who are not in my contacts? For example, I have a canned response that I'd like to send to people who are contacting me for the first time.

Comment: I don't think you can. Not automatically with Gmail by itself.